# OpenCV with ffmpeg on Fedora 22

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, fedora

I am trying to compile OpenCV 3.0 on Fedora 22 with ffmpeg. I encounter the following error:

```
[ 26%] Building CXX object
modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/perf/perf_bitwise.cpp.o
   Linking CXX executable /global/OpenCV/opencv_perf_core
   ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `swr_free'
   ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `swr_init'
   ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `swr_is_initialized'
   ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `lzma_code'
   ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `lzma_end'
   ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `swr_close'
   ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `swr_convert'
   ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `swr_alloc'
   ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0: undefined reference to `lzma_stream_decoder'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/build.make:770: recipe for target '/global/OpenCV/opencv_perf_core' failed
   make[2]: *** [/global/OpenCV/opencv_perf_core] Error 1
   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1245: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all' failed
   make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_perf_core.dir/all] Error 2
   Makefile:136: recipe for target 'all' failed
   make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: Have you searched for these error messages?

Comment: Yes I have, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: nobody answers ffmpeg issues in opencv on linux. sadly. it's a mess.

Comment: I had to install ffmpeg via the rpmforge repository.  Do you have ffmpeg installed on your system?  I am running Fedora 23 and it built fine.  Also, check if the CMake output has ffmpeg configured.

Comment: Thanks msmith81886! I was able to install ffmpeg using rpmfusion.